# Entering password for `git pull` when using `gulp-shell`

Tags: git, shell, ssh

I'm using `gulp-ssh` plugin to have ssh connection to my remote server and then execute shell commands over there. I'm using following gulp code:

```
gulp.task('deploy', function () {
  return gulpSSH
    .shell(['cd /home/username/public_html/example.com', 'git pull'], {filePath: 'shell.log'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('logs'))
})
```

This code executes first shell command successfully, but when it comes to `git pull` it gets stuck there without any message or error. The output is something like below:

```
[15:41:01] Using gulpfile C:\wamp64\www\example.com\gulpfile.js
[15:41:01] Starting 'deploy'...
[15:41:06] gulp-ssh :: shell :: cd /home/username/public_html/example.com
[15:41:06] gulp-ssh :: shell :: git pull
```

My understanding is that it's because `git pull` asks for a password to execute successfully. But when I execute this gulp task it does not ask for any password. How should I proceed from here?

Comment: You should upload your public key from the remote server to your git server.

Comment: I'm using `ssh` only to connect to my remote server, afterward for `git pull` I'm using `https` git url.